# IPFS Installation Error

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to install IPFS on my macbook bro with and following instructions from here:

https://ipfs.io/docs/install/#installing-from-a-prebuilt-package

When I try to run the install bash script:

./go-ipfs/install.sh

I get this error:

> We cannot install ipfs in one of the directories /usr/local/bin
>   /usr/bin It seems that we do not have the necessary write permissions.
>   Perhaps try running this script as a privileged user:
>
> ```
> sudo go-ipfs/install.sh
> ```

I have also tried using `sudo go-ipfs/install.sh` but still run into the same error.

The guys on from here (https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/we-cannot-install-ipfs-in-one-of-the-directories-usr-local-bin-usr-bin/997) say to `move ipfs to usr/bin`, but when i try it the terminal returns `Operation not permitted`.

I will appreciate assistance with this

Comment: I know this is not an answer but, I need to clear my doubt. @Data_Kid, I tried moving to local/bin also but no help. Same problem. I can't comment as I am new here and I require 50 reputation atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a closer look at install.sh script,

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Installation script for ipfs. It tries to move $bin in one of the
# directories stored in $binpaths.

bin=ipfs
binpaths="/usr/local/bin /usr/bin"

# This variable contains a nonzero length string in case the script fails
# because of missing write permissions.
is_write_perm_missing=""

for binpath in $binpaths; do
  if mv "$bin" "$binpath/$bin" 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "Moved $bin to $binpath"
    exit 0
  else
    if [ -d "$binpath" -a ! -w "$binpath" ]; then
      is_write_perm_missing=1
    fi
  fi
done

echo "We cannot install $bin in one of the directories $binpaths"

if [ -n "$is_write_perm_missing" ]; then
  echo "It seems that we do not have the necessary write permissions."
  echo "Perhaps try running this script as a privileged user:"
  echo
  echo "    sudo $0"
  echo
fi

exit 1
```

It tries to write to **BOTH** `usr/bin` and `usr/local/bin`. The issue is that `usr/bin` is read only here the install was failing.

I have to move the `go-ipfs/ipfs` to `usr/local/bin`.

It works nows

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps mentioned on [ipfs.io](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/guides/install/#installing-from-a-prebuilt-package).

> **Download tar file from [this link](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/guides/install/#installing-from-a-prebuilt-package) and then follow these steps**

```
$ tar xvfz go-ipfs.tar.gz
$ cd go-ipfs
$ ./install.sh
```

After successful installation you can check **your ipfs path using following command**

> **`which ipfs`**

it will print path like this

```
/usr/local/bin/ipfs
```